# How to load an opencv dnn model from memory?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, deep-learning

I have a caffemodel and deploy.txt that I would like to load from memory, instead of hard disk.
My thoughts are :

1 - to encrypt these files

2 - attached at the end of a library.so (or an executable)

These steps are ready.

Now,

3 - I would decrypt these files (in memory)

4 - I would like to open these dnn model from memory (instead of files)

I know how to do step 3, but no idea about step 4.

So basically **how do I use `cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe`, but instead of files, from memory?**

Would appreciate even more if the answer is in C++.

Comment: Any ideas anybody ?

Comment: you might have to construct the `Net` object yourself... or use a different library. or check out OpenCV's issues on its github, and if this feature hasn't been requested yet, suggest it.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a solution but a workaround.

You could store the decrypted memory to a file, loaded it and the then delete it immediately after.
In windows you could use FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY with CreateFile() function so the file can avoid writing to disk if the size of cache allows.
In Linux you could use O_TMPFILE flag on the open function which will make sure the file is deleted once the file descriptor is closed (or program crash). But in this last case the file does write to disk no matter the size.